# Expanding an array in an object?

Tags: powershell

I'm using a web request to query my phone system for a list of users and their queue association.  The resulting data is put into an object and eventually output to the screen and into a CSV.  The problem is that many users are members of multiple queues and the resulting queue membership data is returned as an array.

So this is what my output looks like:

```
First Name Last Name   Extension Skill Group                              Skill Level
---------- ---------   --------- -----------                              -----------
Kylo       Ren         1234      {Sales Support, Customer Service}        {8, 8}
Flip       Zimmerman   4321      {Accounting, Marketing}                  {5, 3}
Clyde      Logan       1122      {Sales Support, Customer Service}        {4, 9}
Ronnie     Peterson    2211      {Sales Support, Customer Service,Claims} {4, 9, 1}
Adam       Sackler     1212      Engineering                              2
```

As you can see the "Skill Group" and "Skill Level" columns are represented as arrays and the CSV that's saved just has `System.Object[]` for the cell which is obviously just saying that the cell contains an array.  However if the user is a member of only one skill group then the returned data will be a normal string, like Adam Sackler in the above list.

One of the things I'm struggling with is that I don't know how the data should be displayed?  Some suggestions from you fine folks would be appreciated.

For instance should I dynamically create columns for each skill group and associated skill level?  What happens when a user has fewer, or more, columns than what's already there?

```
First Name Last Name   Extension Skill Group 1 Skill Level 1 Skill Group 2    Skill Level 2
---------- ---------   --------- ------------- ------------- -------------    -------------
Kylo       Ren         1234      Sales Support 8             Customer Service 8
Flip       Zimmerman   4321      Accounting    5             Marketing        3
```

Or should each additional skill group and skill level be on a new line?  Should additional skill group/level be on its own row or just use a carriage return in the cell?

```
First Name Last Name   Extension Skill Group      Skill Level
---------- ---------   --------- -----------      -----------
Kylo       Ren         1234      Sales Support    8
                                 Customer Service 4
Flip       Zimmerman   4321      Accounting       5     
                                 Marketing        3
```

In any case, here's the relevant code that's creating the object with the arrays:

```
[xml]$resourceCsqInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uccxServerBaseUrl"resource?csqid="$($csq.id) -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

[object]$data = $resourceCsqInfo.resources.resource

foreach ($resource in $data) {
    $outputList += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        "First Name"  = $resource.firstName;
        "Last Name"   = $resource.lastName;
        "Extension"   = $resource.extension;
        "Skill Group" = $resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.skillNameUriPair.name;
        "Skill Level" = $resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.competencelevel
    }
}
```

The variables `$resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.skillNameUriPair.name` and `$resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.competencelevel` are the relevant items in the loop.

So my question is this; how do I expand arrays in a object and what's the best way to convey the additional information?

Comment: Take look at https://learn-powershell.net/2014/01/24/avoiding-system-object-or-similar-output-when-using-export-csv/ the "Out-String and Trim()" part would be my go to solution.

Comment: one way to get a property containing a collection into a column is to use `$Collection  -join ';'`. that will  give you the items in the property into a semicolon delimited string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to convey the additional information is going to entirely depend on who or what is consuming it. Formatting the output for a human is going to be different than massaging the output for further programmatic analysis or manipulation.

Generally, the dynamic column option in your first example only works in scenarios when the possible number of columns is very small. And even then, it's still a bit messy to work with both programmatically and understand visually.

The second option is a more human readable version of the output you already have. But the way to make it look like that basically turns it into plain text that you can't do any further work on.

My preferred option is usually a variation on the second option. Instead of trying to omit the Name/Extension data from subsequent skill rows, just duplicate it. So Kylo's original entry with two skills becomes two different Kylo entries each with a different skill. This known in database-world as denormalization.

Within your foreach loop, you're going to have a sub-loop that iterates over the collection of skills and then outputs an object for each skill rather than just one for the individual `$resource`. So maybe something like this:

```bsh
foreach ($resource in $data) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt @($resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.skillNameUriPair).Count; $i++) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            'First Name' = $resource.firstName
            'Last Name' = $resource.lastName
            'Extension' = $resource.extension
            'Skill Group' = $resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.skillNameUriPair[$i].name
            'Skill Level' = $resource.skillmap.skillcompetency.competencelevel[$i]
        }
    }
}
```